# XSLT help - XSL for various similar XML, Template usage

Tags: templates, xslt, xpath

I am very new to XSL and XPath. Apologies if this question shows some stupidity.

I have an XML something like

```
<root>
    <widget name="status">
    ...
        <component name="date">
            <component name="day" label="Fri"/>
            <component name="date" label="4"/>
        </component>
        <component name="time" label="11:23 AM"/>
    ....
    </widget>
    <widget name="foo">
    </widget>
</root>
```

I need to create a DateTime tag which is compose of all the three values something like
Fri 4 11:23 AM

I am writing an XSL for it.

```
<DateTime>
    <xsl:value-of select="(//widget[@name="status"]/component[@name='date'])[1]/@label"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="(//widget[@name="status"]/component[@name='date'])[2]/@label"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="//widget[@name="status"]/component[@name='time']/@label"/>
</DateTime>
```

Question:

1. I am passing the "widget[@name="date"]" to each of the select statement. Is there any better way to shorten the xpath.
2. I need to move this  into a template and call the template. which one I should use call-template/apply-templates?
3. We have a set of similar applications which generate these XML. The above XML is from applicationA. ApplicationB might show the detail in little bit different way, something like `<component name="datetime">Fri 4 11:23 AM</component>`. We have almost 3-4 such application where they display the details in little bit different way.

DateTime is just an example, there are some other details which I also need to capture from these various applications.

I am thinking to write a single XSL to deal with all the applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it with your XML would be this:

```
<xsl:template match="widget">
  <!-- ... -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="create-date-time" />
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="widget" mode="create-date-time">
  <xsl:variable name="date" select="component[@name='date']" />
  <xsl:variable name="time" select="component[@name='time']" />

  <DateTime>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
      concat(
        $date/component[@name='day']/@label, ' ', 
        $date/component[@name='date']/@label, ' ',
        $time/@label
      )
    )" />
  </DateTime>
</xsl:template>
```

> - I am passing the `widget[@name="date"]` to each of the select statement. Is there any better way to shorten the xpath.

Use `<xsl:template>`/`<xsl:apply-templates>`, and relative paths. Store things you need more than once in an `<xsl:variable>`. See above.

> - I need to move this into a template and call the template. which one I should use call-template/apply-templates?

The latter. Always go for `<xsl:apply-templates>` unless there is good reason not to. As a rule of thumb: If you are unsure, then there is no good reason.

> - We have a set of similar applications which generate these XML. The above XML is from applicationA. ApplicationB might show the detail in little bit different way, something like `<component name="datetime">Fri 4 11:23 AM</component>` We have almost 3-4 such application where they display the details in little bit different way.

You could expand the `create-date-time` template to accommodate for this:

```
<xsl:template match="widget" mode="create-date-time">
  <xsl:variable name="date" select="component[@name='date']" />
  <xsl:variable name="time" select="component[@name='time']" />
  <xsl:variable name="dt"   select="component[@name='datetime']" />

  <DateTime>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
      concat(
        $dt/label, ' ',
        $date/component[@name='day']/@label, ' ', 
        $date/component[@name='date']/@label, ' ',
        $time/@label
      )
    )" />
  </DateTime>
</xsl:template>
```

There will be no error if certain components are missing. `normalize-space()` makes sure that there are no excess spaces for any combination of components.

The above may fail if the `date`+`time` and `datetime` components are not mutually exclusive (I've assumed they are). If they are not, or if more complicated cases occur, create additional specific templates, like this one:

```
<xsl:template match="widget[component[name='datetime']]" mode="create-date-time">
  <xsl:variable name="dt"   select="component[@name='datetime']" />

  <DateTime>
    <xsl:value-of select="component[@name='datetime']/@label" />
  </DateTime>
</xsl:template>
```

The `<xsl:apply-templates>` will make sure the correct one is called. Just create specific `match=` expressions for each case that can occur.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer.

Comment: When I am running the first template on the XML provided in question, it's processing it two times which is wrong. I am getting two <DateTime> tags which I donot want.

Comment: @rpg: You could modify the `create-date-time` template so that it does not return anything when there is no date/time info in a widget. It's not that hard. *(Be aware that I've added `<DateTime>` elements to my solution, I've missed them before.)*

Answer (score 0):

**This simple transformation** (16 lines, single template, completely "push" style, no variables, no modes):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match=
 "component
    [contains('|day|date|time|',
              concat('|', @name, '|'))
    ]
 ">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(@label, ' ')"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <widget name="status">
    ...
        <component name="date">
            <component name="day" label="Fri"/>
            <component name="date" label="4"/>
        </component>
        <component name="time" label="11:23 AM"/>
    ....
    </widget>
    <widget name="foo">
    </widget>
</root>
```

**produces exactly the wanted result**:

```
 Fri 4 11:23 AM
```